# Inheritance in jinja2 templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I've question about inheritance in jinja2.

Here is my layout.html looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='header'>Some header stuff</div>
<div id='left-panel'>{% block lpanel %}</div>
<div id='content'>{% block content %}</div>
<div id='right-panel'>{% block rpanel %}</div>
<div id='footer'>Some footer stuff</div>
</body>
</html>
```

3 divs (left and right panels and content) are dynamical and should be filled with some functions.

Now the question: what should i do, to achieve my goal in proper way?

Should I create some child templates here? Or maybe my functions, which create content for those 3 divs should return HTML and I should pass it's result as parameters to layout template? (not the most elegant solution...) Any other way?

EDIT:
thanks for your answers, but unfortunatelly i still have some doubts... i don't know what's the proper way to connect those templates with my flask/python code...

If i had just a layout.html and one child template, which extends the layout, then it's really simple: in python i write a function and end it with something like 'return render_template('child.html', my_varables....)

but here i need 3 functions: one for rendering content of main 'content' div and additional 2 funtions for creating left and right panel. how can i join all 3 of them to get my output page?

Answer (score 3):

Note that you should close `{% block %}` tags by adding a `{% endblock %}` tag.
So it should be like:

```
<div id='left-panel'>{% block lpanel %}{% endblock %}</div>
```

There are [includes](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include) and there are [child templates](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#child-template).

### Includes

You've got a template named `layout.html`.
If you'd like to split your `lpanel`, `content` and `rpanel` blocks, you can create a separate template for it, and then include it:

```
<div id='left-panel'>{% include 'lpanel.html' %}</div>
```

In the lpanel.html do whatever you want to place in that `left-panel` div.

### Child templates

You could also create a base template (let's say your left panel and right panel are always the same). You want to change just the `content`.

You can create a base template (for example, `layout.html`).

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='header'>Some header stuff</div>
<div id='left-panel'>Some stuff</div>
<div id='content'>{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
<div id='right-panel'>More stuff</div>
<div id='footer'>Some footer stuff</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let's say you want two pages on your site - "About me" and "News".

You create two templates: `about.html` and `news.html`, and extend them with the base template.

about.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}Hey! I'm mkay and I'm learning about Jinja2!{% endblock %}
```

news.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}2015-02-13: I joined StackOverflow.{% endblock %}
```

You don't have to put anything else in these child templates - they'll just overwrite whatever you have placed in it (in this example, we overwrote just the `content` block).

Answer (score 1):

In my view, what you are trying to achieve can be accomplished by using your current html as a parent and separate child html pages for your `left-panel`, `right-panel` and `content`.

You can use the below as an outline to create your child pages :
(This specific eg. is for `block content`. You can replace `content` with `left-panel` or `right-panel`)

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content/l %}
<!--what ever html you want fill-->
{% endblock %}
```